# Sorting a map of pair and double

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, std-pair

I have a map as: `map< pair < int , int > , long double> valore`. Where the pair represents my coordinate system and the double the value in the (i,j) coordinates.

Now I have to sort this map from the smaller to the higher double (obviously the coordinates must be linked to the corresponding double). Can someone help me?

Comment: Swap the map key and values (ie. `std::map<long double, std::pair<int, int>>`) and you have it sorted for free.

Comment: Maps are already sorted.  You can't change that

Comment: Do you need help to sort a particular map? Give us one then and we will sort it for free!

Comment: [Boost bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned it's not directly possible to sort map using the values. 
One way to sort the map using values is as follows.

- Create a vector with map elements as a pair. ie, `pair<Value, Key>`. In your case this would be `vector< pair<double, pair<int, int> > >`
- Sort the vector (using a custom sort function), now you have your elements sorted by values.

See the following example. (compiled with `-std=c++11` option)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

/* custom compare function. ascending order. Compares first elemens of p1 & p2 */
static bool custom_compare(const pair< double, pair<int, int> > & p1, const pair<double, pair<int, int> > & p2) {
        return p1.first < p2.first;
}

void sortfn(map<pair<int, int>, double>& m) {

        /* vector if pairs to hold values. */
        vector< pair<double, pair<int, int> > > vec;

        /* traverse the map and populate the vector */
        for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++) {
                vec.push_back(make_pair(it->second, it->first));
        }

        /* call sort method on the vector with custom compare method */
        sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), custom_compare);

        for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
                cout<<it->first<<" ( "<<it->second.first<<", "<<it->second.second<<" )"<<endl;

        }
}
int main() {

        map<pair<int, int>, double> m;

        m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(0, 0), 5));
        m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(1, 1), 0));
        m.insert(make_pair(make_pair(2, 2), 10));

        sortfn(m);



        return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0 ( 1, 1 )
5 ( 0, 0 )
10 ( 2, 2 )
```

Comment: You may even drop your `custom_sort` (which is not a function to **sort** but to **compare**, `custom_less` would be a better naming (or `less_by_first`)). it will just specify order for element with same double.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. In this case, we don't need the custom sort function.

Comment: @Jarod42 makes sense. Renamed the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have just to write a custom comparator. Here you must build a full object because you will want to compare keys according to their value in a specific map. This should meet your requirements:

```
class Comparator {
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double>& orig_map;

public:
    Comparator(std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double>& orig_map)
    : orig_map(orig_map) {}

    bool operator () (const std::pair<int, int>& first,
            const std::pair<int, int>& second) const {
        return orig_map[first] < orig_map[second];
    }
};
```

You can use it to build a specially ordered map from an original map:

```
std::map< pair < int , int > , long double> valore;
// load the map valore ...

// build a copy of valore sorted according to its value
Comparator comp(map);
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double, Comparator> val_sorted(valore.begin(),
    valore.end(), comp);
```

You can iterate `val_sorted`, it is sorted by its values

Beware: never insert in `val_sorted` and element that would not exist in `valore`. The correct way to use it is to create one new instance each time the original map could have changed, or at least empty it and reload it again.

Comment: You cannot even modify first map with a modification which will change the order of second map. else UB :/

Answer (score 0):

As the below map contains first argument as pair of integers and second argument as double, it is not possible to sort based on first argument (pair of integers).

```
 map< pair < int , int > , long double> valore
```

A custom function needs to be written for sorting based on the co-ordinates.